# One textbox to search three fields of a CCK content type, how?

Tags: drupal, search, drupal-6, drupal-views, cck

I have a CCK content type which is composed of node `Title`, `Color`, `Width`, `Height`, `Comment`.

Currently I have a view with *one* exposed field `Title` to search content.

Is it possible to make the single search field (`Title`) to search on more than one field, such it will search in any of `Title`, `Color` or `Comment`?

It's not desirable to expose three fields for the purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I used is [here](http://drupal.org/node/578620#comment-2750454)
While it sounds complicated, this is the simplest and most useful.
If you need further help, don't hesitate to contact me.